# UITestControlNotAvailableException - Internet Explorer Window is not available in Coded UI Tests

Tags: coded-ui-tests

When runnning my Coded UI Tests through a VM (deployed via OctoDeploy incase that matters) 2 of my tests will run properly. The other 44 however do not. I am presented with the exception:
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotAvailableException: The Internet Explorer window is not available.

When looking at the output, it shows that it passes 2 steps, which the second step involves clicking a link. It states that it passes this step, and when I watch it physically, it doesn't look like it does. (I even attempted to take control real quick and click it, but it did nothing).

Has anyone else had these problems?

Comment: Are you managing your BrowserWindow between tests? What does your Initialization class and Cleanup class look like?

Answer (score 0):

So looks like I found the answer to this through different means entirely. It was due to the security of the VM and I had to enable Java applets. Sorry for this everyone.